# How to make javascript regular expression match any char and carriage return?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a html file like below.

```
  <body>  
    <p>Enter your phone number with area code and then click 
        Check The expected format is like</p>
    <form action="#">  
      <input id="phone"><button onclick="testInfo(document.getElementById('phone'));">Check</button>
    </form>  
  </body>  
</html>
```

I use below script which can print right result.

```
fs.readFile('test.html', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    var re = /<p>[a-zA-Z1-9\s\r\n]*<\/p>/i;
    var myArray = data.match(re);
    console.log(myArray);
});
```

the result: `'<p>Enter your phone number with area code and then click \r\n        Check The expected format is like</p>'`

But I want to use regular expresstion like below.

```
re = /<p>[.\r\n]*<\/p>/i;
```

But it print null. How to fix it? Why I can not use `.` to replace `a-zA-Z1-9\s`  thanks.

Comment: Because the dot is inside the character class, and we be matched as a literal dot. Try `<p>[\s\S]+?<\/p>` instead. Btw, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: The reason is that a dot within a character class (`[...]`) looses its "superpowers" - meaning it is only a dot. What you possibly want is `re = /<p>[\s\S]+?</p>/i;` but please be warned that it is nod advisable to parse `HTML` structures with a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that a dot within a character class (`[...]`) looses its "superpowers" - meaning it is only a dot.
What you possibly want is `re = /<p>[\s\S]+?<\/p>/i;` but please be warned that it is nod advisable to parse HTML structures with a regular expression:

```js
let html = ` <body>  
    <p>Enter your phone number with area code and then click 
        Check The expected format is like</p>
    <form action="#">  
      <input id="phone"><button onclick="testInfo(document.getElementById('phone'));">Check</button>
    </form>  
  </body>  
</html>`;

re = /<p>[\S\s]+?<\/p>/i;
var myArray = html.match(re);
console.log(myArray);
```